# Conditional helm hook

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

How to run a helm hook based on a condition.

What I want to solve: 
I have created a postupgrade hook which will load some data to service A, which is created from a zipped subchart.
Right now it runs every time when an upgrade happened.
I want it only run when the service A or the job itself has been upgraded.

Is it possible on helm or k8s level?

Comment: (Do you have a potential issue with this setup with multiple replicas of A, or if the cluster kills and recreates the A pod, maybe because a node failed?)

Comment: @DavidMaze   Right now I dont have any issue, but I dont want to run the job when it is not necessary.Would be a surplus pod creation.

Answer (score 2):

Not really. It doesn't have enough info to know when that is the case.